# How can I allow other users to open up my gitLab static web-page?

Tags: html, gitlab

I created a web-page using gitLab pages. Very basic as you'll see below.  All I want to do is allow my team to be able to automatically access the page rather than log in every time.  I created an access token.  But not sure how to incorporate that into my code.
Thank you in advance for any feedback.

index.html

```
<h1>Test Page</h1>
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - main
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Under Settings > Pages there is a section that says "Access Pages" and provides a link to your custom page.  I was typing in the wrong link.  Maybe that'll help someone else :)

Also, below is a bit of helpful info:

"To make your website publicly available, navigate to your project's Settings > General > Visibility and select Everyone in pages section. Read the documentation for more information."